# _AddressOfReturnAddress() equivalent in Clang/LLVM

Tags: c, visual-c++, llvm, clang, addressof

Visual C++ has [an intrinsic function called `_AddressOfReturnAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s975zw7k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which returns the *address* of the current function's return address on the stack.

**Note** that this is *not* the same as [`_ReturnAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/64ez38eh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which only returns a *copy* of the return address.

Is there any equivalent for `_AddressOfReturnAddress` in Clang/LLVM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [rustyx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485343/rustyx) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944119/addressofreturnaddress-equivalent-in-clang-llvm#comment53640214_23980330), Clang/LLVM (and GCC) provides `__builtin_return_address()` which is equivalent to `_ReturnAddress()`. Clang/LLVM also provides `__builtin_frame_address()` which (*depending on the particulars of your ABI, architecture, etc.*) may be somewhat analogous to `_AddressOfReturnAddress()`.

As an example, the following code...

```
std::cout<< ((int64_t) __builtin_return_address(0)) << ' '
         << ((int64_t) __builtin_frame_address (0)) << ' '
         <<*((int64_t*)__builtin_frame_address (0)+1)<<'\n';
```

...prints the following on an [OS X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X) machine.

```
140735807202733 140734600362944 140735807202733
```

Comment: +1 not that I need it or have the chance to check it anymore, but I think this was probably the solution I ended up going with too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No. [LLVM IR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM#Intermediate_representation) does not provide an intrinsic for this.

Comment: There is no equivalent for `_AddressOfReturnAddress` but there is `__builtin_return_address` which is the equivalent for `_ReturnAddress`.